# changing the authentication parameters in Laravel 5.3 with Hesto multi Auth

Tags: laravel-5

I wan't to change the login parameters in authentication. I'm using the Hesto Multi Auth package.

By default  Hesto package gives a multi authentication with email and a password. Instead what i wan't to do is change it to a local identity number and the password.

[Hesto_Package](https://github.com/Hesto/multi-auth)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite simple.
All i had to do is override the login() function in the required model's LoginController Class. If the Modeis admin then in adminAuth -> LoginController.

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    echo $request->NIC;
    if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt(['NIC' => $request->NIC, 'password' => $request->password])) {
        //
    }
}
```

then also add the field in Models class file.4

protected $fillable = [
        'NIC', 'email', 'password',
    ];